# Referencing beans without an id

Tags: spring, el, spring-el, activiti

I'm trying to reference a JPA repository using Spring expression language in Activiti. However since Spring is creating the repository beans using `<jpa:repositories/>`, they don't have an id associated with them. Is there a way to use SpEL to reference a bean of a certain type instead of by id? I tried using what I thought would be the generated name (locationRepository) for the `LocationRepository`, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `LocationRepository` is an interface, and that the backing implementation is being generated for you.  When Spring creates a bean and no id is explicitly specified, it usually uses the class name of the implementation class to determine the bean id.  So in this case your `LocationRepository`'s id is probably whatever the name of the generated class is.

But since we don't know what it is, we can create a Spring `FactoryBean` which just gets `LocationRepository` from the app context via autowiring and puts it back into the app context under a new name.

```
public class LocationRepositoryFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<LocationRepository> {
    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository bean;

    public Class<?> getObjectType() { return LocationRepository.class; }
    public Object createInstance() throws Exception { return bean; }
}
```

In your app context xml:

```
<bean name="locationRepository" class="your.package.LocationRepositoryFactoryBean"/>
```

You should then be able to refer to your `LocationRepository` object with the bean id locationRepository.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I posted this before I went on a long weekend. It makes sense that they bean name is the generated class not the interface name, and that is why I can't reference it. Thanks for the possible solution!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this in SPEL but you can use [`@Qualifier`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) to decide which bean should be injected.

If you want you can create your own custom @Qualifier annotation and access bean based on it.
Like

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier  // Just add @Qualifier and you are done
public @interface MyRepository{

}
```

Now use `@MyRepository` annotation in repository bean and other place where you want to inject it.

```
@Repository   
@MyRepository  
class JPARepository implements AbstractRepository    
{
  //....
}
```

Injecting it

```
@Service 
class fooService   
{
    @Autowire 
    @MyRepositiry
    AbstractRepository repository;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't completely solve my problem, but is good to know, thanks for the input =)